# What makes something offensive?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, offensive

I was offended by a comment directed at me today (no link, as it has already been deleted), so I flagged it as rude/offensive. It was declined.

Does that declination mean "I, the mod or high-rep user reviewing this flag, was not personally offended" - i.e., is the rude/offensive flag intended to denote content that would offend anyone who sees it, not just the person it was directed at? In situations where the remark in question was only offensive to the individual at whom it was directed, is it better to raise a custom flag explaining that someone has taken offense at the posted content?

TL;DR: Does "offensive" mean "this offended someone"?

To explain the situation further, a new user asked a very basic question that could've been answered in a few seconds by Googling their question's title. A high-rep user with a gold badge in that tag stopped by and, instead of taking the few seconds to close as a duplicate, answered the question. I asked him why he didn't just close it, and his response wasn't "heh heh, sometimes I just can't resist" or "I was just bored, I guess" or "sure, I'll close this one now." He started by going through my profile, looking for answers to questions that were eventually closed as duplicates. He then presented these answers as evidence that I occasionally answer questions that eventually get closed as duplicates, extrapolating this into "and therefore you have no right to even suggest that someone else ever VTC as duplicate instead of answering."

I told him that I had tried to find good duplicates for those but was unsuccessful (or sometimes a question doesn't seem common so I don't think to search for duplicates), so I answered them. I mean, I could've answered the question we were on (it was really, really basic - even the asker could've answered it if they'd had the patience for 5-10 seconds of research) but I VTC as duplicate instead, so I thought it was apparent that I try my best to VTC as duplicate instead of answering. I also said that my failures don't mean that failure is okay.

Then he dismissed me and said he had more important things to do with his time.

Am I really so wrong to be offended about this? Was I being just as not-offensive as this high-rep user wasn't not being? If you asked a high-rep user to moderate the site a bit more carefully and they responded by telling you that A) you have no right to talk about that and B) they have more important things to do than talk to you, would you really not be offended?

Comment: I don't suppose you remember what the comment said?

Comment: Well, good to see these flags getting declined, it was getting out hand rather badly.  Just use "Not constructive" instead if the comment does not improve the odds for a better Q+A.

Answer (score 15):

> Does "offensive" mean "this offended someone"?

No. Some people are so thin-skinned that they're offended by downvotes and close votes. That can't be the yardstick we use.  If you flag a question or answer as "rude or offensive" you get a description.

> A reasonable person would find this content [inappropriate for respectful discourse](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

There are more details and examples on the "Be Nice" page if you follow the link. If you're genuinely offended by something, go ahead and flag it. If you're just grasping your pearls because someone disagreed with you or told you your question is off-topic, please don't waste a moderator's time.

Comment: It was more along the lines of "I have better things to do than to waste my time talking to you." Was I really wrong to be offended at that?

Comment: Yes, you were wrong. That may have been slightly rude, but in no way was offensive.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 if you want an answer to this specific case. You and another (no need to name them here) seemed to criticise each other as to why you both sometimes answered questions instead of finding dupes. It had some bickering from both of you in the same tones (noisy/unconstructive - but hardly rude/offensive) and I saw no need to approve your flag (you were giving as good as getting) - so I declined it and just nuked all the comments.

Comment: I didn't know I was being offensive at all. I suggested he close the question as a duplicate instead of answering it, he lashed out with "you did it worse here! and here! so there!", I explained that I'm trying my best and someone else's failures don't make failure desirable, and he said that I wasn't worth his time. Was I really being as offensive as he was? Really? Suggesting he VTC and saying that I try my best to do so is as bad as saying "well you do it worse" and "you're not worth my time"?

Comment: Forgot to answer this part: "if you're genuinely offended by something" - yes, I was genuinely offended, especially since I thought this particular high-rep poster and I were on friendly terms. It made a bad day that much worse. That's why I raised the flag. I thought that's what it was for.

Comment: typo here, "people are so thin-skinned" should read "so much better to be a _reptile_" :)

Comment: So, just to confirm here: ending a conversation with "I have more important things to do" is considered acceptable behavior on SO?

Comment: Whatever it is, It is [not used very often](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/338958)...

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I agree that it's a bit rude, but the offensive flag should be reserved for more severe cases like threats or hate-speech. Those flags go to a separate list so moderators can handle them immediately. Someone rudely ending a conversation can be handled with a regular flag, or just ignored.

Comment: @gnat: Surprised nobody has flagged this answer yet, considering.

Comment: Ah, okay. I didn't know it was a special flag. I'll use a different flag when I find something rude/offensive, but not incredibly so.