# Should I flag comments which accuse someone of doing it just for reputation?

Tags: discussion, offensive

Is it appropriate to flag a comment, which accuses someone of having done something only for reputation? Which flag should I use?

Comment: Maybe. Depends. See [What makes something offensive?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299834), especially the comments.

Comment: It's definitely not essential to the answer/question at hand, and should be flag-able using the "not constructive" option, provided that is the sole purpose of the comment

Comment: @DJDavid98: Thanks. I generalized my question to make it more useful.

Comment: Context is everything. I do see comments and flags from time to time about *only doing it for reputation* which could be construed as offensive, often where the commenter / flagger doesn't understand our system (such as the fact that we encourage self-answers). Offence is in the eye of the beholder however.

Comment: If you're referring to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300071/why-was-this-10-0-question-deleted-after-i-asked-for-reopening?noredirect=1#comment225096_300071 I'd say it *implies* rather than *accuses*.

Comment: ... and anyway, that's on meta and actually an integral part of the discussion, and thus *not flaggable*.

Comment: Could someone explain me, what's wrong with this question and why it's down votes?

Comment: @Deduplicator: That means it's important why someone did it, not what he did? That doesn't sound objective.

Comment: As Hans and Martjin said, context is king. It's not a straight-out denunciation, not even accusatory, but context to your request there. Is it relevant that you have a personal interest in the decision? Well, there's no way to argue that it distorted the decision, because that was well over by then. But it explains why you kept at it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Why would someone ask a question without a personal interest? Besided that please stay on-topic, this question is answerable without external ressources.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer: Why wouldn't you ask question a decision which does not directly and immediately effect *your posts*? And you should have mentioned that from the beginning, because it might colour your judgement, and it certainly explains why you kept at it after it was made clear the decision was right. Also, just because you don't like the discussion/explanation takes, doesn't make it an off-topic tangent.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Of course it's off-topic. It doesn't help to answer this question. If you want to discuss that further, comment it on the other post.

Answer (score 5):

Context is everything, but in many cases such a comment is probably accurate.  Gamification is a big deal at the StackExchange sites, it is one of the principal mechanisms they use to get their users spending many hours of their free time on their web sites.

So a response to such a comment could look like:

> Well, yeah, duh.

But such a response is liable to be a lot less graceful, users sure don't like to be reminded about it and certainly favor the idea that they are using their free time in more charitable ways.  Like helping other programmers.

None of this ultimately accomplishes anything that comments are *supposed* to accomplish: constructing better Q+A.  It is the ultimate example of a "non-constructive" comment.

There's a flag reason for that, use it.

Comment: Well, if it's [as jonrsharpe guesses](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300116/should-i-flag-comments-which-accuse-someone-of-doing-it-just-for-reputation#comment225339_300116) (only implied, on meta, [see here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300071/why-was-this-10-0-question-deleted-after-i-asked-for-reopening?noredirect=1#comment225096_300071)) then non-constructive doesn't actually work.