# Is it offensive/rude to vent about or insult a product or library?

Tags: discussion, offensive

A question in a tag that I follow had some "color commentary". Excerpts from [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/51014634/2) for context (please be wary of [the meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/1426891) before voting or intervening too harshly):

> **Title:** "Dagger 2 and dependency injection hell?"
>
> How on earth do you use dagger?
>
> Is this really too much to ask?
>
> Why the heck do I need to [...]. This is plain stupid
>
> Now I see why it's called dagger, you feel like you are getting stabbed by a dagger as you try to use this thing

Though I'm sure it was cathartic to the poster, I think that a majority of that language is unhelpful to future readers and searchers. Typical remedies would be to downvote and comment, or to simply edit out the noise. (Without the additional text, there is a valid problem to be solved, though it's currently phrased as several broad questions.)

However, one could also argue that the commentary is a little more than *unnecessary*, and strays into *unprofessional*. It's not quite profane (if we count phrases like "DLL hell" as terms of art), and it's not directed at any person on the site, but it's a little more acerbic of a rant than I'm used to seeing on SO. This would imply that it might be better marked rude or offensive, or flagged for moderator attention (if only to keep track in case it recurs or worsens). That said, if it's appropriate enough to keep in, I don't want to rob anyone of the opportunity to write their question in their own voice.

I've looked elsewhere on Meta for guidelines on this (e.g. [What makes something offensive?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299833/1426891)), but most of the responses I've seen are about person-to-person offense, or offensive edit summaries or source code.

**How should we treat product-targeted insults or rants like these?** Are they far enough below community standards to flag, or are they forgivable turns of phrase that should simply be edited out and left in the post history? Or is this too a mild case to intervene, but perhaps more-aggressive insults to a product/library/language should be flagged?

Comment: It's noise. If you have the time and energy to edit it out, please do. If you don't, then at the very least please downvote it.

Comment: @yannis Fair assessment; I ask first because [this well-received answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359870/1426891) advocates _against_ editing if the post is rude or offensive. I'm more trying to get a sense of whether the community thinks it actually is, or where it draws the line.

Comment: It's an open source project maintained by actual people so in my opinion it is rude and I can imagine the people who created it might find it offensive, though that is for them to decide. Either way, it doesn't really contribute anything, might as well edit it in my opinion.

Comment: @JeffBowman You forgot the _"pure"_ part there. The other post is about complete spam/rude posts but your question here is about an actual (although colorfull) question so I don't think that applies here.

Comment: No, such a post is not rude or offensive, please don’t flag it. Such posts are not purely offensive so please do edit the post to adjust the tone.

Comment: Its a rather tame rant, it only targets a thing. We live in an age where people casually make [death threats to developers](https://www.google.com/search?q=game+sequel+death+threats&oq=game+sequel+death+threats). If you're offended by a piece of tech you worked on being slagged off... well then you had better get some counselling to help you manage your emotions. No need to go further on Stack Overflow than edit out the off-topic content as this is not a site to place reviews or rant.

Comment: Let's face it, everyone who has got past the first hour of 'Computers 101' has cursed the compiler/linker.   It does not conflate with insulting the team of people who developed the compiler, it's just human behaviour when faced with machinery that will not operate as desired.

Comment: It's distracting and unprofessional and shouldn't be in a question, especially not when repeated ad nauseam, but it's not offensive unless it stoops to the level of directly asserting that the developers or the users of the Despised Thing are inferior, unworthy or incompetent. And even then, editing those bits out is enough if the text does actually address the substance of the matter.

Comment: In the case of dagger, the best description may be "accurate"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A surprisingly controversial question (+5/-5)! To quote moderator [Martijn Pieters ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) in the comments:

> No, such a post is not rude or offensive, please don’t flag it. Such posts are not purely offensive so please do edit the post to adjust the tone.

The consensus does seem to be that valid and on-topic questions/answers with similar impersonal negative noise should be *edited to remove the noise* and *possibly downvoted*, but *without flagging the post directly*.

Comment: Phrased another way, use a flag when you can't ameliorate the problem.  Editing ameliorates the problem so no flag is necessary.

Comment: @Makoto Agreed, of course, now that we have consensus on whether the post constitutes rude/offensive (it doesn't). If the community decided the other way, we likely wouldn't want the older revision in the post history, which we couldn't ameliorate ourselves and which _would_ require moderator intervention.

Answer (score 4):

If the post was *just* a rant, it would be flag-worthy as [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Since it does contain a question, anything not related to the question itself should be edited out as noise, leaving only the relevant facts -- the same as with disclaimers.